# video storage for an video based Android app

Tags: android, video, storage

I'm not sure how to approach the next problem.
I'm developing a video based app which has to play different short video clips estimated at around 300 MBs.
Packaging the clips locally will probably cause less people to download it, and in the Apple App Store I don't think it's even possible due to the 100MB limit.(?)

How do I tackle the problem if I'm interested in downloading the clips to the user's device (while he uses the app) from a storage server?
What are my options?

Comment: 300MBs is a very large size for short video clips. Nonetheless, you should put those videos on network storage and stream them on Android devices. Once played, cache them on External Storage. I believe this is the universally preferred way.

Comment: 300MB is the total size of all the clips combined. Question is, what storage? Parse is ok?